# Lotus Notes - Move email to folder quickly

Tags: lotus-notes

I have several folders to manage emails in a Lotus Notes database.
And I want to move email(s) to a specific folder just by a few key strokes.
It would act like this:
1. Click a button (It seems one cannot create a user-defined shortcut for user command)
2. prompt an ComboEdit box, whose options are the folders in current database.
3. input a few letters and the filtered results shows.
4. Choose the folder and press {enter}, the email(s) gets filed.

Just like **Launchy** to start a MS Windows application. 
Is it possible to do this by using the @function and @command?

I've got some info here:

> @Prompt([OkCancelEditCombo]; "Select a Database"; "Select a database to open, or type a database specification."; "Schedule"; "Schedule":"Phone Book": @Subset(@MailDbName;-1))

So how can I get a list of folder and to enable step3 to work?

Answer (score 1):

In my Lotus Notes client I move my mails to a folder by just doing the following:

- Click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>
  (the number and the letter depend on the version and language of your mailtemplate, 5 is the fifth Button in the action- bar and "M" is the underlined letter for the action "Move to folder")
- Start typing the name of the folder where you want to put the mail
- Press Enter

No need to write even one line of code... And it even searches for folders CONTAINING the text, that I typed, not only folders STARTING with that characters...

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no capability in Notes formula language or even in LotusScript that could allow typing a few characters and filtering the available folder names without requiring the user to press the Enter key or click on something first.

Answer (score 0):

You could mock that up in a dialogbox using the onchange event of a dialoglist field that allows new values and doesn't define any values -- you would have to calculate the matching values yourself and put them up as the choices in a second keyword field. Or you could take advantage of the typeahead of the dialogbox field and give it all the folder names as its choices, but that wouldn't work *exactly* as you described.

BTW did you have a look at SwiftFile for Notes?